# Request a changing URL without manually changing the URL value

Tags: python, api

So I'm doing an API call from a URL on a website, i found the url using inspect, however that URL constantly changes value every time the price is updated. I want my code to be able to API call this URL every time even if it has changed without me having to manually rewrite the correct URL.

```
url = 'https://lirarate.org/wp-json/lirarate/v2/rates?currency=LBP&_ver=t20227159'

#API CALL
def LiraRateApiCall():
    R = requests.get(url)
    timestamp = R.json()['buy'][-1][0]/1000
    format_date = '%d/%m/%y'
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    buyRate = R.json()['buy'][-1][1]
    print(date.strftime(format_date))
    print(buyRate)
    return (date.strftime(format_date),buyRate)
```

Comment: can you please share how you currently find the right url using inspect?

Comment: I press inspect, then Network then refresh the current exchange price, which makes the url i need popup, however once in a while this url changes (for example here it is ver=t....159 it might become ver=t...172)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `_ver` that changes is a timestamp, how to use it properly would normally be specified in a API documentation (which seems not to be existing for your case).

However this works for now:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%Y%#m%d%H")


currency = 'LBP'
_ver = date_time 

base_url = "https://lirarate.org/wp-json/lirarate/v2/rates"
final_url = f'{base_url}?currency={currency}&_ver=t{_ver}'


print(final_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get you right, but it looks your URL is correct, and the only case it becomes incorrect is when you need another date. In such case just pass new date and time in **_ver** variable.

Also don't forget to pass headers and cookies in your request. You may make some experiments to define which parameters are required.

For example, I requested data with _ver=20227152:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

cookies = {
    'ezoadgid_2523476': '-1',
    'ezoref_252346': '',
    'ezosuibasgeneris-1': '99sdfe7-04bc-4913-6e5b-dca4c5c908e1',
    'ezoab_223476': 'mod1',
    'active_template::2524376': 'pub_site.165734434',
    'ezopvc_2523476': '1',
    'ezepvv': '154',
    'ezovid_2223446': '223423419',
    'lp_252876': 'https://lirarate.org/',
    'ezovuuidtime_2523476': '16243934',
    'ezovuuid_252876': 'c0de3ea5-c7f1-23424-7b8b-243dee02f6a8d',
    'ezds': 'ffid%3D1%2Cw%3D1920%2Ch%3D1243',
    'ezohw': 'w%3D1920%2Ch%3D937',
    '_ga': 'GA1.2.8352432927.12472934',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.832436768.162342934',
    '_gat_gtag_UA_15492438_1': '1',
    'ezouspvv': '0',
    'ezouspva': '0',
    '__gpi': 'UID=000008b2347f14599:T=1657234935:RT=16578723435:S=ALNI_MaG2hYLAD3uXSqdNlk5qKmpBHsE_g',
    '__cf_bm': 'BisAuukdgfMENr.kaqLcAbdfgy1z6Qny8OnEsTwRkU-1657823435-0-AZ9wbvFo11c+1KtX4vss2HnQ7V1OVHVRbu8ahZMGweqRos3lwckmf5mJHJMqWnA4BtvhRqmnItUqqw4rtV10qHcTAczgcsHOdfgCQz9pJMma2F+yyOkfQ00D5J5iLlk7Q==',
    '__gads': 'ID=3c1182323432e370a:T=1652243935:S=ALNI_MaSKQDO9csVw-TCwUtwMv4btORNbw',
    '__qca': 'P0-852923494-165234935168',
    'ezux_et_252876': '1',
    '_hjSessionUser_2823484': 'eyJpZCI6IjMyNmQyODA3LTQ4MTQtNTRlNi04MGE5LWQ0MjAwOTE3NDNjZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTc4NzI5NDM0NzcsImV4aXNsdfgnIjpmYWxzZX0=',
    '_hjFirstSeen': '1',
    '_hjIncludedInSessionSample': '0',
    '_hjSession_2823484': 'eyJpZCI6ImYxZDMyOTY3LTlmODYtsdfgMC05YzMwLWUzMjgyMDhmNzkyNCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTc4NzI5NDM0OTQsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=',
    '_hjIncludedInPageviewSample': '1',
    '_hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress': '0',
    'ezux_lpl_2243876': '165787224310|dc7eb915-ec87-4d4f-5a1a-b4b2d04535b8|false',
    'ezux_tos_25223476': '14',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'lirarate.org',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7',
    'authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbGlyYXJhdGUub3JnIiwiaWF0IjoxNjUzMTE2NzgwLCJuYmYiOjE2NTMxMTY3ODAsImV4cCI6MTY4NTI1NzU4MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiMiJ9fX0.lLQdsfgt7YxgStkZwntAx2RMRWwNQ8f7mMkznfhCLJXAc',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    # Requests sorts cookies= alphabetically
    # 'cookie': 'ezoadgid_2234876=-1; ezoref_2234876=; ezosuibasgeneris-1=243e3a9e7-04bc-4913-6e5b-dca4c5c908e1; ezoab_2523476=mod1; active_template::2522346=pub_site.1657872934; ezopvc_2523476=1; ezepvv=154; ezovid_2523476=2523419519; lp_252876=https://lirarate.org/; ezovuuidtime_252876=1657872934; ezovuuid_252876=c0de3ea5-c7f1-4424-7b8b-74dee02f6a8d; ezds=ffid%3D1%2Cw%3D1920%2Ch%3D1080; ezohw=w%3D1923420%2Ch%3D937; _ga=GA1.2.8243927.16234934; _gid=GA1.2.83423468.162342934; _gat_gtag_UA_1549234428_1=1; ezouspvv=0; ezouspva=0; __gpi=UID=00234b967f14599:T=16572342935:RT=16523472935:S=ALNI_MaG2hYLAD3uXSqdNlk5qKmpBHsE_g; __cf_bm=BisAuukoUMENr.kaqLcAbTHj1By1z6Qny8OnEsTwRkU-1657823435-0-AZ9wbvFo11c+1KtX4vss2HnQ7V1OVHVdsfgu8ahZMGweqRos3lwckmf5mJHJMqWnA4BtvhRqmnItUqqw4rtV10qHcTAczgcsHOKfYPCQz9pJMma2F+yyOkfQ00D5J5iLlk7Q==; __gads=ID=3c118819432e370a:T=165723435:S=ALNI_MaSKQDO9csVw-TCwUtwMv4btORNbw; __qca=P0-85223494-162345168; ezux_et_252876=1; _hjSessionUser_2867084=eyJpZCI6IjMyNmQyODA3LTQ4MTQtNTRlNi04MGE5LWQ0MjAwOTE3NDNjZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTc4NzI5NDM0NzcsImV4aXN0aW5nIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjFirstSeen=1; _hjIncludedInSessionSample=0; _hjSession_2867084=eyJpZCI6ImYxZDMyOTY3LTlmODYtNDhkMC05YzMwLWUzMjgyMDhmNzkyNCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NTc4NzI5NDM0OTQsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; ezux_lpl_223476=16578722340|dcsdf915-ec87-4d4f-5a1a-b4b2d04535b8|false; ezux_tos_252876=14',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'referer': 'https://lirarate.org/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'currency': 'LBP',
    '_ver': 't20227152',
}

response = requests.get('https://lirarate.org/wp-json/lirarate/v2/rates', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)

df = (pd.DataFrame(data = response.json()['buy'], columns = ['timestamp', 'buy']).set_index('timestamp')
 .join(pd.DataFrame(response.json()['sell'], columns = ['timestamp', 'sell']).set_index('timestamp')))
df.sample(10)
```

it returns

| timestamp | buy | sell |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1642613914000 | 23300 | 23200 |
| 1548590400000 | 1515 | nan |
| 1642157572000 | 28250 | 28150 |
| 1631179791000 | 19600 | 19550 |
| 1648040455000 | 24000 | 23900 |
| 1629211179000 | 18700 | 18600 |
| 1610026178000 | 8675 | 8625 |
| 1626971924000 | 21150 | 21100 |
| 1600256142000 | 7600 | 7550 |
| 1556625600000 | 1515 | nan |

Comment: To get this headers and cookies just copy curl bash from Networks tab in your browser and convert this curl to python code or extract values yourself.